# How to set a Referer on an android WebView in KitKat and up

Tags: android, webview, android-webview, android-4.4-kitkat

KitKat got the new Chromium based WebView however now it no longer passes the Referer header through. I've always done the following (which always used to work but as of KitKat no longer does):

```
headers.put("Referer", referrer);
webView.loadUrl(someUrl, headers);
```

Debugging with Charles Proxy I can see that no Referer header is passed. If I rename the header to something like "Referrer" (with two r's) it goes through fine, although that's not a solution since the header is Referer with one r.

If anyone has a working solution for passing the Referer header in Android WebView's on KitKat and higher I'd appreciate any help!

Comment: Same Problem and still no solution

Comment: Found this issue in google groups: https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=72323. It seems as there is no solution and will be fixed with next android version.

Answer (score 2):

Same problem. I've found a great workaround. If Android version is 4.4.3 or 4.4.4, pass the header "Referer " (with final space). Works perfect!

Comment: Awesome. Thanks a lot! It works. But it only works for 4.4, not the later version. For later versions, we need to use without space.